# Linux Mint - Display zoom whilst using multiple screens

Tags: linux-mint

I'm using three displays of which one is a 4K resolution screen (the others are the usual 1080p thing). Now that I'm using Mint I'm encountering reading difficulties due to the high resolution of my 4K screen which makes the system display everything like really tiny. I searched for a solution online and checked the display settings in the preferences, however, I was unable to find a configuration or something. Thing is that I don't need the zoom for all the three screens, but for one in particular. Using Windows, there's an built-in option for it.